# Sfdx vs code Extension causes high cpu load

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, extension, node-salesforce

I used to work on Vs code for lwc development . I am not aware of the previous version but After Updating to version : 1.51.1 .

- Authorize an Org : Redirecting to Browser but after logining in the Instance . It is not showing the org authorized . (Keeps on loading ) .
- I'm unable to load or retrieve components from existing authorized org's browser .
  I dont find stash.json file in .sfdx folder .
  [image]
  I have uninstalled multiple times and Tried installing Previous versions but nothing worked .

Version :
Visual Studio Code version : 1.51.1
Salesforce Extension pack : 50.8.0
Sfdc client in machine :  sfdx-cli/7.74.1-32db2396ed win32-x64 node-v12.18.3
Windows 10 Home - 64 bit .

Sfdx plugins --core :

> sfdx plugins --core
> @oclif/plugin-autocomplete 0.1.5 (core)
> @oclif/plugin-commands 1.3.0 (core)
> @oclif/plugin-help 3.2.0 (core)
> @oclif/plugin-not-found 1.2.4 (core)
> @oclif/plugin-plugins 1.9.0 (core)
> @oclif/plugin-update 1.3.10 (core)
> @oclif/plugin-warn-if-update-available 1.7.0 (core)
> @oclif/plugin-which 1.0.3 (core)
> @salesforce/sfdx-trust 3.4.3 (core)
> alias 1.1.1 (core)
> analytics 1.12.1 (core)
> config 1.1.8 (core)
> generator 1.1.3 (core)
> salesforcedx 49.10.0 (core)
> ├─ custom-metadata 1.0.10 (core)
> ├─ templates 49.4.4 (core)
> ├─ apex 0.0.9 (core)
> ├─ salesforce-alm 49.11.0 (core)
> └─ @salesforce/sfdx-plugin-lwc-test 0.1.7 (core)
> sfdx-cli 7.74.1 (core)

Need urgent help , If any way to connect via google call or any sort that would be helpful . Any suggestion is apppreciated . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's usually an extension acting up.  In the command palette, run this to see all extensions and their startup time:

```
Developer: Show Running Extensions
```

Disable every extension that you can and restart the IDE.  If things are behaving in a performant fashion, that's the issue.

Source: it happened to me last month :)

Comment: can you add an image of where exactly I need to click to run this? thank you

Comment: These are mostly text-based commands.  Use the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+P to open the command palette.  It's also under the view menu, I believe.  Then enter "Developer: Show Running Extensions" to see the results.